# MySQL - Show Month and Dates

Tags: mysql

MySQL version  5.7.29-log

My table (events) has EventID, EventTypeID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime

I want to extract the month's name and then the dates of the records for that month, and output as follows: "September: 21, 22, 30".

Each row should show the output for any records that have events in that month, e.g.

```
January: 21, 22
March: 2, 3, 9
...
December: 3, 6, 9
...
```

Notes: the dates should be in ascending order, and the months should be in order. Moreover, it should be based on EventTypeID (group by).

I've tried searching for this, but I need help finding help that includes every day of the month, where a record exists.

This is the code I tried, but it's not close to what I need.

```
SELECT
  eventid, EventTypeID,

  IF (
    DAY (startdatetime) = DAY(EndDateTime),
    concat( DATE_FORMAT(StartDateTime, '%M'),': ',  DAY (StartDateTime)), 
    concat( DATE_FORMAT(StartDateTime, '%M'),': ',  DAY (StartDateTime),        ' & ',      DAY (EndDateTime)   )
) as Days
FROM
    `events`
WHERE
    `events`.StartDateTime > now()
Group by EventTypeID, month(StartDateTime)
order by month(StartDateTime)
```

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Events` (
`EventID`  int NOT NULL ,
`EventTypeID`  int NULL ,
`StartDateTime`  datetime NULL ,
`EndDateTime`  datetime NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`EventID`)
)
;
```

Sample Data (25 Rows):

```
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11139', '670', '2023-03-28 08:30:00', '2023-03-29 08:30:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10937', '1', '2023-03-21 08:00:00', '2023-03-21 14:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11161', '713', '2023-03-29 08:30:00', '2023-03-30 08:30:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10938', '64', '2023-03-21 08:00:00', '2023-03-21 09:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10969', '61', '2023-03-22 08:00:00', '2023-03-22 14:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10967', '27', '2023-03-23 09:00:00', '2023-03-23 15:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11093', '126', '2023-03-27 10:00:00', '2023-03-27 19:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11094', '710', '2023-03-27 10:00:00', '2023-03-27 18:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10970', '3', '2023-04-12 08:30:00', '2023-04-12 23:30:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10939', '1', '2023-04-26 08:30:00', '2023-04-26 14:30:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10972', '60', '2023-04-12 08:30:00', '2023-04-12 14:30:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10973', '61', '2023-04-14 08:00:00', '2023-04-14 14:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10917', '721', '2023-04-01 08:30:00', '2023-04-02 08:30:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11180', '21', '2023-04-15 10:00:00', '2023-04-15 18:30:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10953', '53', '2023-04-05 09:00:00', '2023-04-05 21:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11186', '673', '2023-04-19 10:00:00', '2023-04-19 15:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10954', '64', '2023-04-05 09:00:00', '2023-04-05 10:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11091', '126', '2023-04-22 10:00:00', '2023-04-22 19:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10901', '670', '2023-04-11 08:30:00', '2023-04-12 08:30:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11092', '710', '2023-04-22 10:00:00', '2023-04-22 18:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11130', '721', '2023-05-20 08:30:00', '2023-05-22 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('11151', '670', '2023-05-21 08:00:00', '2023-05-22 08:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10941', '53', '2023-05-04 09:00:00', '2023-05-04 21:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10995', '27', '2023-05-23 09:00:00', '2023-05-23 15:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10942', '64', '2023-05-04 09:00:00', '2023-05-04 10:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10945', '1', '2023-05-26 08:00:00', '2023-05-26 14:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10977', '61', '2023-05-06 08:00:00', '2023-05-06 14:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10997', '3', '2023-05-30 08:00:00', '2023-05-30 23:00:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10892', '25', '2023-05-16 08:30:00', '2023-05-16 14:30:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`EventID`, `EventTypeID`, `StartDateTime`, `EndDateTime`) VALUES ('10999', '60', '2023-05-30 08:00:00', '2023-05-30 14:00:00');
```

I have a feeling that `group_concat` may be of use here, but I am not clear on how to integrate it.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Lol. Thanks. I updated my post. Hopefully, it's more practical.

Comment: you might also want to add which MySQL version you have in mind, as they have different capabilities.

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks. Done. ( 5.7.29-log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not awfully clear what you want to achieve, as your sample only contains one even per month per event type, but perhaps this will get you going:

```
select 
  EventTypeID
  ,mo
  ,group_concat(d order by d separator ', ')
from (
  
SELECT
  EventTypeID,
  month(StartDateTime) mo,
  day(StartDateTime) d
FROM
    `events`
WHERE
    `events`.StartDateTime > now()
) t
Group by EventTypeID, mo
order by mo
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QZdIe2ho) (which you should have created by the way).

Comment: This did exactly what I needed it to do. Much appreciated. Thank you. (This fiddle has more data that allows more per EventTypeID and Month. [link] (https://dbfiddle.uk/ArUPbKR0)